# Visitor pattern apply on shared_ptr or raw pointer?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I am working on a small compiler. Now i have a hierarchy system to express the Abstract Syntax Tree(AST).

```
class Ast{
public:
    // ...
}

class Expr : public Ast{
public:
    // ...
}

using ExprNode = shared_ptr<Expr>;

class BinaryOp : public Expr{
public:
    ExprNode lhs;
    ExprNode rhs;
}
```

All the class in the `Ast` hierarchy system use shared_ptr to manage their member(if needed), for example, the `BinaryOp` holds two member to express its operand.

I'd like to apply visitor pattern on the tree to produce IR code for the AST.   My problem is, should the visitor accept raw pointer as parameter, or accept shared_ptr as parameter, which may import `shared_from_this`(consider the pros and cons)? If shared_ptr is need, should i use pass it by value or by reference?

---

#### Raw pointer

```
class AstVisitor{
public:
   virtual Ast* visit(Ast* ast);
   virtual Ast* visitBinaryOp(BinaryOp* binary){
      visit(binary->lhs.get());
      visit(binary->rhs.get());
      // ...
   }
}

class Ast{
public:
    virtual Ast* accept(AstVisitor& visitor);
}

class BinaryOp:{
public:
    virtual Ast* accept(AstVisitor& visitor) override{
        return visitor.visitBinaryOp(this);
    }
}
```

#### shared_ptr

```
using AstNode = shared_ptr<Ast>;
using BinaryOpNode = shared_ptr<BinaryOp>;
class AstVisitor{
public:
   virtual AstNode visit(AstNode ast);
   virtual AstNode visitBinaryOp(BinaryOpNode binary){
      visit(binary->lhs);
      visit(binary->rhs);
      // ...
   }
}

class Ast : public enable_shared_from_this<Ast>{
public:
    virtual AstNode accept(AstVisitor& visitor);
}

class BinaryOp:{
public:
    virtual AstNode accept(AstVisitor& visitor) override{
        return visitor.visitBinaryOp(static_pointer_cast<BinaryOp>(shared_from_this()));
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe you misunderstood the `language-lawyer` tag. Its for questions concerning the rules of the language (beyond fixing compiler errors), which does not really apply here

Comment: You might want to compare your ideas to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant or simply use ``std::variant``. It could save you a lot of lines of code and time.

Comment: A visitor can accept a reference just fine.

Comment: @BitTickler could you explain it more clearly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that [C++ Core Guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines.html#c-core-guidelines) edited by B. Stroustrup and H. Sutter would be helpful for this problem.
Please note [**this guideline**](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines.html#r30-take-smart-pointers-as-parameters-only-to-explicitly-express-lifetime-semantics):

> **R.30: Take smart pointers as parameters only to explicitly express lifetime semantics**
>
> **Reason** Accepting a smart pointer to a widget is wrong if the function just needs the widget itself. It should be able to accept any widget object, not just ones whose lifetimes are managed by a particular kind of smart pointer. A function that does not manipulate lifetime should take raw pointers or references instead.

For instance, in your `BinaryOp` class, managing child nodes with `shared_ptr` is a good practice.
Each node has it's parent as an owner and these `shared_ptr`s keep the subtree alive with RAII semantics. (`std::unique_ptr` would be more preferable because each node has a single parent which is a single owner.)

OTOH, since your `visit` and `visitBinaryOp` seem to just need `Ast` and `BinaryOp` themselves respectively, **accepting a raw pointer (or a reference if possible) would be preferable in this case**.

Comment: Intuitively, i guess most classes of the AST hierarchy system have ```unique_ptr``` semantic to its sub-tree, but i am not sure that all of them have unique semantic when go on the further analysis.

Comment: @user8510613 thx :). Although this is just my experience, I seldom need to use std::shared_ptr. When I want to use pointers, almost always my first pick is std::unique_ptr which makes ownership relations and our code clearer. But I think it definitely depends on the details of your implementations. I hope you will go well.

Answer (score 2):

A function accepting a `shared_ptr` tells to the reader that it makes a copy of it and keeps it after the function returns.

Functions should not take `shared_ptr` unless they make a copy of it.